# Can't reach my flask api running on port 5000 from other devices on the network. Tried firewall. Tried router. Stumped

Tags: android, networking, firewall

I am working on an Android app using a Windows 11 pc as both the app dev environment and also a flask/python backend api for it.

I can get the app in the emulator to reach the api at its address, ie. 192.168.0.100:5000.  But the same address on my phone and other laptop just returns a timeout.

I've tried adding inbound rules to the windows machine firewall (local port 5000, remopte port all ports).

I've tried disabling the firewall.

I've tried adding port forwarding on the router from 5000 to 5000 for the reserved IP of the pc.

I am running the flask app as host=0.0.0.0 from the command line

Nothing seems to work.  The service works fine when I'm on the pc both from browser, postman, and the android emulator.  But it's dead everywhere else on the wifi and I need to be on an actual phone to properly test everything.

I'm at the end of my networking knowledge and don't know where else to look.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on WiFi, especially not a home/SOHO model, there is the possibility that the Wifi doesn't allow connections between the local network. This is often described as "peer-to-peer connections".

You can try to isolate the problem a couple ways, like using Ethernet (even if you just borrow it to confirm the problem).

If you phone can hotspot, you can try that as well. I worked out of some locations where I had this problem, and I would use my phone to hotspot Expo  dev laptop, an iPhone (hotspot) and a test Android device over the phone's Wifi.

Comment: Thanks, but I've used this same network for peer to peer browsing on a different server, a Chromebook running linux.  Php pages on port 80 worked fine.  However that server isn't running any more so I don't have it to test.  I did try running flask on port 80, no change.

Also I spent some time in a chat with a rep at Spectrum and they confirmed it should work on their router.

I am at home FYI.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, in this era, everything has layered networking features, and none of them have adequate documentation (or troubleshooting instructions).